# Azure update management stop services on vm using pre script runbook

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine, auto-update

I have a number of VM's that I've scheduled automated updates for. Some of them have specific services running on them that I would like to stop and start gracefully in the case that a reboot is necessary during the update process. I've got the below template but it's failing...I would appreciate if anyone could help me with this...

The script looks like this...

```
<# 
.SYNOPSIS 
 Stop a service on an AzureRM using RunCommand 

.DESCRIPTION 
  This script is intended to be run as a part of Update Management Pre/Post scripts.  
  It uses RunCommand to execute a PowerShell script to stop a service 

.PARAMETER SoftwareUpdateConfigurationRunContext 
  This is a system variable which is automatically passed in by Update Management during a deployment. 
#> 

param( 
    [string]$SoftwareUpdateConfigurationRunContext 
) 

#region BoilerplateAuthentication 
#This requires a RunAs account 
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
$ServicePrincipalConnection = Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName

Add-AzureRmAccount ` 
    -ServicePrincipal ` 
    -TenantId $ServicePrincipalConnection.TenantId ` 
    -ApplicationId $ServicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId ` 
    -CertificateThumbprint $ServicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 

$AzureContext = Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $ServicePrincipalConnection.SubscriptionID 
#endregion BoilerplateAuthentication 

#If you wish to use the run context, it must be converted from JSON 
$context = ConvertFrom-Json  $SoftwareUpdateConfigurationRunContext 
$vmIds = $context.SoftwareUpdateConfigurationSettings.AzureVirtualMachines 
$runId = $context.SoftwareUpdateConfigurationRunId 

#The script you wish to run on each VM 
#VM Name = ***
$scriptBlock = @" 
Stop-Service -Name "service1"
Stop-Service -Name "service2"
"@ 

#The cmdlet only accepts a file, so temporarily write the script to disk using runID as a unique name 
Out-File -FilePath "$runID.ps1" -InputObject $scriptBlock 

#Start script on each machine 
$vmIds | ForEach-Object { 
    $vmId =  $_ 

    $split = $vmId -split "/"; 
    $subscriptionId = $split[2];  
    $rg = $split[4]; 
    $name = $split[8]; 
    Write-Output ("Subscription Id: " + $subscriptionId) 
    $mute = Select-AzureRmSubscription -Subscription $subscriptionId 
    Write-Output "Invoking command on '$($name)' ..." 
    Invoke-AzureRmVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $rg -Name $name -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath "$runID.ps1" -AsJob 
} 

Write-Output "Waiting for machines to finish executing..." 
Get-Job | Wait-Job 
#Clean up our variables: 
Remove-Item -Path "$runID.ps1"
```

The errors seem to be an issue with the syntax or formatting...They're all similar to the below error but on different terms/commands.

**-ServicePrincipal : The term '-ServicePrincipal' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

At line:22 char:5

- -ServicePrincipal `
- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (-ServicePrincipal:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
  - FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException**

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Did you install the AzureRM powershell modules in your automation account?

Comment: @JoyWang Yes the powershell modules are installed. I'm trying to do it using a graphical runbook now but struggling to find a cmdlet to stop or start a windows service on the VM. The names in the toolbox are quite confusing.